# Python. Регулярные выражения как разделить слово на слова MichaelJordanDepOfDefense предложения с пробелами

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, текст, split

Python. Регулярные выражения как разделить слово на слова "MichaelJordanDepOfDefense" или "JordanSmithWorthy2" предложения с пробелами. Где разделить большие буквы и цифры

"MichaelJordanDepOfDefense" => "Michael Jordan Dep Of Defense"

"JordanSmithWorthy2" => "Jordan Smith Worthy 2"

а если предложение разделено то ничего не делать

"Michael Jordan and Barack Obama at the White House" => "Michael Jordan and Barack Obama at the White House"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярное выражение: `(?<=[a-z0-9])[A-Z0-9]`.

***Пример:***

```py
import re


string = 'MichaelJordanDepOfDefense'
result = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z0-9])[A-Z0-9]', r' \g<0>', string)
print(result)
```

***stdout:***

```py
Michael Jordan Dep Of Defense
```